# Webpack with node backend on single process/same port with hot reload for both front and back…?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, koa2

I have a pretty standard setup with a node backend that serves an SPA as a webpack bundle as well as the api serving that SPA application. The backend is using koa2.

So I have had hot reload working just fine for the front end part but I now have a bit more work on the backend and need to make my roundtrips faster.

I'm wondering what the best approach is. I started out by:

### 1. Bootstrapping from webpack

I used webpack-serve which at the time seemed standard and added the KOA as middleware in the webpack config:

```
serve: {
  add: app => {
    require('./src/node/backend')(app)
}
....
```

This however doesn't hot reload the backend and it's pretty painful since I have to restart the whole webpack-serve command on a backend change then.

So then I tried

### 2 Bootstrapping from the node backend with webpack as middleware

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const koaWebpack = require('koa-webpack')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const app = new Koa()

const config = require('../../webpack.dev.js')
const compiler = webpack(config)

koaWebpack({ compiler }).then(middleware => {
  require('./backend')(app) // delegate to the common
  app.listen(process.env.port)
  app.use(middleware)
  return app
})
```

This works fine too for frontend but I still have no reloading of backend so basically the same experience.

### 3. Running webpack-dev-server and backend as different processes.

This works fine and then I can use `nodemon` for the koa backend which is good enough for me, but I then have to do some shuffling of ports I think.

I guess webpack-dev-server/webpack-serve can act as proxy and pass stuff through to the backend unless it hits any of my frontend stuff. But it all feels tedious. I'd rather stick it all together on the same port.

So is there any other easy way to have the two builds hot reloaded but still running together on the same port…?

I found this project https://github.com/vlazh/node-hot-loader, that might be interesting, but I really felt the need to ask before if I'm missing something more obvious since I'm actually happy with restarting my server nodemon style… (it's small and fast)

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching I found a few tools tackling this, but they all used webpack for bundling the server side code too which I feel is overkill for me at this point.

I ended up doing an in-app reload for the server side, staying in alternative 2 above. So for the koa backend I just added a file watch to invalidate the require cache for the dev server:

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar')
const watcher = chokidar.watch('.')
watcher.on('ready', () => {
  watcher.on('all', () => {
    Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(id) {
      if (id.indexOf('src/node') > 0 && id.indexOf('node_modules') < 0) {
        delete require.cache[id]
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Then an indirection so one always passes the require in dev:

```
const reloadable =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? id => (ctx, next) => require(id).then(r => r(ctx, next)) : id => require(id)
```

which I then use in all the route definitions like:

```
const use = app.use.bind(app)
reloadable('./auth').then(use)
reloadable('./users').then(use)
reloadable('./ingredients').then(use)
```

This was good enough for me.